# Getting "except ManifestInvalidRevisionError, e:" upon initializing a repo from Code Aurora

Tags: python, linux, git, repo

I am running a git command for creating a repo inside `folder`

```
repo init -u git://codeaurora.org/quic/le/le/manifest.git -b release -m <manifest-file>.xml --repo-url=git://codeaurora.org/tools/repo.git --repo-branch=caf-stable
```

but I am getting the following error

```
  File "/home/user/parent/folder/.repo/repo/main.py", line 126
    except ManifestInvalidRevisionError, e:
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

At some other times, I also got the following:

```
 File "/home/user/parent/folder/.repo/repo/main.py", line 56, in <module>
    from subcmds.version import Version
  File "/home/user/parent/folder/.repo/repo/subcmds/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    ['%s' % name])
  File "/home/user/parent/folder/.repo/repo/subcmds/upload.py", line 27, in <module>
    from hooks import RepoHook
  File "/home/user/parent/folder/.repo/repo/hooks.py", line 472
    file=sys.stderr)
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

and I see a warning regarding upgrading to python 3.6+.

Not sure what's causing it. Is it possibly related to a python version?

Comment: The SyntaxError means the code is intended for Python 2 and you tried to run it under Python 3.

Comment: but `python -V` tells me I'm using python 2.7

Comment: `head -1 $(which repo)` ?

Comment: `/usr/bin/env python`

Comment: Looks good. Then the error is strange.

Comment: How'd you verify if python 2.7 is being used?

Comment: I'd rather do it the other way: force Python 2.7 in the command line: `python2.7 $(which repo)`

Comment: The 2nd SytnaxError is a code for Python 3 running under Python 2. What a mess!…

Comment: running `python2.7 $(which repo)` returns the same error as the 2nd one I mentioned in the description

Comment: @Jazzy I am also facing same issue.Have you got solution for this ?

Comment: I think the solution was to upgrade the python version to 3.6

Comment: python 3.10 has the same issue. anyone figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved issue by cloning repo again and set Permission & PATH.
git clone git://codeaurora.org/tools/repo.git

sudo chmod 777 repo

export PATH=/repo/:PATH

Comment: downloading repo from codeaurora does not work. same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is two different version of repo. In my case I installed the latest from google: https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo and in the repo init command, downloads it from here: git://codeaurora.org/tools/repo.git

Get the latest repo version from Google, and omit this variable "--repo-url" from your repo init command.